# receiving json via ajax asp.net issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json, web-services

I am trying to receive a json data using ajax asp.net.
i have got a web service with a web method -

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Song> GetSongListByMood(string Mood)
{
    SongBL songbl = new SongBL();
    return songbl.GetSongListByMoodBL(Mood);
}
```

and i have got the javascript code -

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var cssSelector = {
            jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
        };
        var playlist = [];
        var options = {
            swfPath: "./js",
            supplied: "mp3"
        };
        var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);
        $("#slider a").click(function () {
            var mood = $(this).text();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "AvironaService.asmx/GetSongListByMood";
            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseXML.text);
                    myPlaylist.playlist = obj;
                }
            };
            var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
            var qs = 'Mood=' + mood;
            xhr.send(qs);
        });});
```

now basically what im trying to do is get the data from the server using ajax in json format and put the data in the playlist variable

Comment: So what's the issue? And why not use the built in $.ajax method of jQuery? it wraps most of your ajax code in a single method. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to say the issue, i receive a empty data

Comment: I would start with a tool such as Firebug of Fiddler2 to see what the response you're getting is...

Comment: You have jQuery, why are you using `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `$.ajax()`?

Comment: this is the thing when I am using fiddler2 i enable to see the data but when i try to alert the data in javascript the browser show undefined content...

Comment: well never used $.ajax() method.. dont really know how to use thatr

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a few changes.

1. Change your method to return a `string` instead of `List<Song>`.
2. add a using statement `using System.Web.Script.Serialization`.
3. Create an instance of `JavaScriptSerializer` and use that to serialize your object and return the results.

So...

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]     
public string GetSongListByMood(string Mood)
{
    SongBL songbl = new SongBL();
    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return jss.Serialize(songbl.GetSongListByMoodBL(Mood));
}
```

Change your AJAX code to leverage the JQuery methods available:

```
$("#slider a").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        "url" : "AvironaService.asmx/GetSongListByMood",
        "type" : "post",
        "data" : {"Mood" : $(this).text()},
        "dataType" : "json"
        "success" : function(data){
          myPlaylist.playlist = data;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside your method are you properly passing your Mood?

Comment: So if you can set a breakpoint inside the method what is the result of the return value.  Are you using the debugger?  I am getting the feeling you are not...

Comment: `[{"ID":1,"Name":"Viva La Vida","Artist":"Coldplay","Album":"Viva la Vida or Death and All His Friends","Genre":"Alternative rock","Mood":"Happy","Year":"\/Date(1211662800000)\/","Length":241,"Url":"EqWLpTKBFcU&amp;feature=autoplay&amp;list=PLD94B179B47905683"},{"ID":2,"Name":"Fix You","Artist":"Coldplay","Album":"X&amp;Y","Genre":"Alternative rock","Mood":"Happy","Year":"\/Date(1125867600000)\/","Length":282,"Url":"JI-o25K6B-E&amp;feature=autoplay&amp;list=PLD94B179B47905683"}]`

Comment: I rewrote your AJAX to use the JQuery ajax method.  Not sure if the AJAX call is the issue, but it is easier to deal with.  With Fiddler what does it say is the content-type header say in the response header?  The response header "Content-Type"  should be "application/json" or some other variation of JSON.  That could be the root of the issue.

Comment: thank you for your help i have changed the ajax code to jquery.. as you said. it still doesn't work, i checked the Content-Type in the fiddler and its: text/xml; charset=utf-8 maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Check out the latest edit `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]` should set the content type to be correct.

Comment: nope, i have changed the content type to the latest edit,still no response. but when i changed the ajax code to - <code>            $("#slider a").click(function () {
$.ajax({
"url": "AvironaService.asmx/GetSongListByMood",
    "type": "post",
                    "data": { "Mood": $(this).text() },
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "success": function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    "error": function (data) {
                        alert("bla");
                    } 
});
}); </code> this alert bla..